# VBA check if IE url has been changed

Tags: vba, api, internet-explorer, oauth-2.0

I've been looking around but can't seem to find an answer to this question.
I'm currently trying to connect to an API with oauth2.

I am able to present the login screen in IE pretty easily.

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim url as string
url = "www.loginpage.com"


IE.Navigate url
IE.Visible = True
```

Whenever the username and password have been entered the url changes to the redirect url with an authorization code.
I would like to store this redirect url to another variable, so I can subtract the authorization code and use this for the next step.

I've been trying with a simple if, but without any luck so far.
The first url variable is filled with the url to display the loginpage.
So I figured if the current url differs from that url it can be stored in a new variable.
Sadly I'm getting an Runtime error 80004005.
Maybe you guys know a better way to do this?

```
Dim url As String
Dim newurl  As String

If IE.Document.url <> url Then

newurl = IE.Document.url
MsgBox (newurl)

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your result is formated, but it will be more easily to use :

```
Dim Url As String
Dim dataFromResponse As Collection

Dim Client As New WebClient
Dim Request As New WebRequest
Dim Response As New WebResponse

EnableLogging = True

Client.BaseUrl = "https://YOUR_CALL"

Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)

If (Response.StatusCode = Ok) Then
    Set dataFromResponse = Response.Data
End If
End Sub
```

With the result, you extract the AuthToken

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `ie.LocationURL` to get the url. I made an example with bing and it can work well:

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set ieA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ieA.Visible = True
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://www.bing.com/"
    ieA.navigate url
    Do Until ieA.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set doc = ieA.Document
    doc.getElementById("sb_form_q").Value = "VBA"
    doc.getElementById("sb_form_go").Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    
    Dim newurl  As String
    If ieA.LocationURL <> url Then
    newurl = ieA.LocationURL
    MsgBox (newurl)
    End If
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]